# JuliaSetPlot - how do I achieve nicer colors?

Tags: plotting, color, visualization, fractals

I use the following code to generate images of Julia sets:

```
JuliaSetPlot[
   z^2 - 0.76 - 0.11 I, z, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.6, 1.6}, {-1.0, 1.0}}, 
   MaxIterations -> 1000, 
   ImageResolution -> 1500
]
```

[image]

As you can see the colors are not too appealing. However I did code Julia sets in C# before and I know that the colors depend on the number of iterations so I tried less iterations:

[image]

This is what `MaxIterations -> 100` gives me. I much prefer these colors. How can I get nicer colors while keeping a high number of iterations? I think `ColorFunction` or `ColorFunctionScaling` could get handy here but I never touched those so some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can scale the values supplied

```
JuliaSetPlot[z^2 - 0.76 - 0.11 I, z, PlotRange -> {{-1.6, 1.6}, {-1.0, 1.0}}, 
 MaxIterations -> 1000, ImageResolution -> 1500,
 ColorFunction ->
  With[{cf = ColorData["M10DefaultFractalGradient"]},
   cf@Sqrt[#3] &
   ]
 ]
```

[image]